# Opening particular version of Flash by process.start()

Tags: c#

I am using the following code to open flash:

```
private Process flash = new Process();
flash.StartInfo.FileName = ("Flash.exe");
flash.Start();
```

The target machine has many version of flash like flash cs5,4,3. I want to open the newest version or let the user choose, how can I possibly do that?

Comment: Quick question: can you assume they are all installed in a common folder? Like Adobe/Flash CS3, Adobe/Flash CS4 etc.?

Comment: What does navigating to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`show, in relation to flash? Is there just one Flash.exe there?

Comment: No i can not assume they are all installed in a common folder.

Comment: Hum but on my machine it is Flash.exe There with path of the Flash cs5 that is the only version install on my machine. But on my friend's pc it is Flash.exe with path of the Flash 8 where there are Flash 8 and Flash cs5 install on his machine. Where path of the cs5 is not in the app paths it having a separate folder in the software   with name adobe and there is path for cs5 and flash 8 there

Comment: But this is also not certain behavior as my another friend had Flash cs5 and Flash 8 but no folder name with adobe in the software

Comment: Hey, I found a way to fetch all the installed programs in a forum thread (just like in the Add/Remove programs dialog), it might be useful to you, since it gets you really close to your goal!

Answer (score 0):

Typically speaking, all other flash installations would be in different program folders, so you would just need to make sure you're running Flash.exe from the right folder. For instance, my current installation lies here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS5\Flash.exe`, but an alternate one could very well be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Flash CS4\Flash.exe`.

An important thing to notice is that **you can't assume the user installed flash CS* in its default directory**! You should always query the Windows registry to find the list of installed products.

Also, another notice would be that you don't need parentheses around string literals. So you can just write:

```
string foo = "Hello!";
```

instead of

```
string foo = ("Hello!");
```

### Edit 1:

Hey, I found a similar problem being treated in a [forum thread here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=598355)! I downloaded the code sample and ran it through a vb.net -> C# converter ([like this one](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)) and got it to work after a few minor syntax tweaks. Now it's able to output a list of the installed programs with their appropriate version numbers.

There will be a bunch of methods that get programs form e.g. certain users. All of these will then be placed in a common list, returned to the user. Now, this seems perfect, but there is just one flaw - no path is available... so far!

You can just query the UninstallString, and get a path to the uninstaller (which is IIRC in the same folder as Flash.exe). For instance, in GetUninstallKeyPrograms, after the

```
try
{
    IsSystemComponent = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentSubKey.GetValue("SystemComponent", 0));
}
```

snippet, you can try to get the UninstallString value in order to obtain the path. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for you response. 1)I need to query windows registry to find the list of installed product. 2) I need to find out How many flash version are there 3) Then what is the highest version. [Can you provide me code for this.]

Comment: You're welcome! Did you finally manage to detect the various versions of Flash?

Comment: I get the all the list of Software with there installation path and version.

Comment: Now I want to filter them for the different Adobe Flash Version where I need to avoid the Flash Player and also need to support upcoming version including current can you give me some boost thought for this.

Comment: Hey I resolve this to I filter them by the name Adobe Flash Professional where we only support Adobe Flash Professional cs5,cs4,cs3 and if in future will be cs6 :)

Comment: You can always use a regular expression to be future-proof! :D `Regex expression = new Regex(@"adobe flash professional cs\d+(\.\d+)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` and then just check the name with `if(expression.IsMatch(name)) { ...`